# From pandas dataframe, how to find the number of duplicate comments for each user?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with list of usernames and their comments, see format below.

What would be the quickest and most efficient approach to find repetitive duplicate comments (spam) for each user?

Dataframe format:

```
Author  | Comment
casy    Nice picture! 
linda   I like this 
casy    Nice picture! 
tom     I disagree 
bob     Follow me 
bob     Follow me 
bob     Follow me 
bob     Follow me 
casy    Nice picture! 
casy    Wow! 
linda   Interesting post 
linda   Check my profile
bob     Dissapointing
casy    Wow!
```

I want to get the result in the following format, so the resulting table would be:

```
Author  | Number of dup. comments (descending)  | Comment   
bob     4   Follow me 
casy    3   Nice picture
casy    2   Wow! 
bob     1   Dissapointing 
linda   1   I like this 
linda   1   Check my profile
linda   1   Interesting post 
tom     1   I disagree
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) first, then [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), create columns by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and last if necessary change order of columns by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = (df.groupby(['Author', 'Comment'], sort=False).size()
       .sort_values(ascending=False)
       .reset_index(name='Number')
       .reindex(columns=['Author','Number','Comment']))
print (df)
  Author  Number           Comment
0    bob       4         Follow me
1   casy       3     Nice picture!
2   casy       2              Wow!
3    bob       1     Dissapointing
4  linda       1  Check my profile
5  linda       1  Interesting post
6    tom       1        I disagree
7  linda       1       I like this
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I get NaN values for the Number column and the values are not aggregated. I'll try to see maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I created temp df (https://pastebin.com/gEKEvFXV) and it did work perfectly. trying to figure out what's wrong with my original df. It does contain other columns (_id, title), may this be an issue? @jezrael

Comment: Another columns are not important. Are data confidental?

Comment: Ok, it worked. I had typo in Number. Thanks. So to get the number of the same comments regardless of the Author I just remove "Author" from groupby and reindex?

Comment: @user40 - Do you think only by `Author` like `df.groupby(['Author'], sort=False).size()`?

Answer (score 1):

### Intuitive `value_counts`

... with a method intended for this purpose

```
df.groupby('Author').Comment.value_counts().sort_values(
    ascending=False).reset_index(name='Number')

  Author           Comment  Number
0    bob         Follow me       4
1   casy     Nice picture!       3
2   casy              Wow!       2
3    tom        I disagree       1
4  linda  Interesting post       1
5  linda       I like this       1
6  linda  Check my profile       1
7    bob     Dissapointing       1
```

---

### `pd.factorize` and `np.bincount`

```
f, u = pd.factorize(list(zip(df.Author, df.Comment)))
a, c = zip(*u)
pd.DataFrame(dict(
    Author=a, Comment=c, Number=np.bincount(f)
)).sort_values('Number', ascending=False)
```

---

### `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter

pd.Series(
    Counter(zip(df.Author, df.Comment))
).rename_axis(['Author', 'Comment']).reset_index(name='Number')
```